# How do I find DOMAIN\accountname$ of a remote AD-joined computer?

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, wmi

I want to store a remote computer's account name in a variable in the `DOMAIN\Accountname` format (preferably `DOMAIN\Accountname$`. I know the DNS name and samaccountname of the computer, and I want to run the script on a domain-joined computer (not a domain controller).

I cannot find any simple one-line approach to get the account name in that format. I can manually construct the string by concatenating the NETBIOS domain name with computer name (samaccountname), but I was assuming there is an easier and more robust way of doing this.

So is there any built-in approach of getting the computer name in the `DOMAIN\Accountname$` format without having to manually constructing the string? I assume that's common task.

Comment: What is so hard about using a plus sign to join two strings?

Comment: @jdweng it's not hard. I was just assuming that there has to be a more elegant, built-in way.

Comment: If running locally `(Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName`

Comment: Assuming you have permissions to remotely query the computers then my last comment in addition to `-ComputerName ComputerToQuery` should work

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at the environmental variables. For this question, I would do the following...

```
$strUserAndDomain = ((Get-Content env:userdomain) + "\" + (Get-Content env:username))
```

Then you can user the value of $strUserAndDomain whenever you want.

Comment: The question is about computer accounts of remote computers (e.g., `CONTOSO\MyComputer$`, so `$env:username` unfortunately does not work here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).